# How do I put multiple boxplots in the same graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, rstudio, boxplot

Sorry I don't have example code for this question.

All I want to know is if it is possible to create multiple side-by-side boxplots in R representing different columns/variables within my data frame. Each boxplot would also only represent a single variable--I would like to set the y-scale to a range of (0,6).

If this isn't possible, how can I use something like the panel option in ggplot2 if I only want to create a boxplot using a single variable? Thanks!

Ideally, I want something like the image below but without factor grouping like in ggplot2. Again, each boxplot would represent completely separate and single columns.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ggplot2` requires that your data to be plotted on the y-axis are all in one column.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  value = runif(810,0,6),
  group = 1:9
)

df

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(group), value)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,6)
```

[image]

The `ylim(0,6)` sets the y-axis to be between 0 and 6

If your data are in columns, you can get them into the longform using `melt` from `reshape2` or `gather` from `tidyr`. (other methods also available).

Comment: NOTE: for ggplot2 `ylim()` subsets data for display of boxplots. use `coord_cartesian(ylim = )` instead

Comment: Thanks, @jalapic! So I wound up using tidyr and ggplot2 per your recommendation: `long <- gather(team1, variable, value, var1:var44) ggplot(long, aes(factor(variable), value)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,6))` but wound up with this strange looking plot: http://tinypic.com/r/261z0qg/8. I assume I just have too many variables for this to look reasonably good; in this case, are there any options for resizing, or should I just give up and use panel plots? Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this if you [reshape](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/reshape.htm) your data into long format

```
## Some sample data
dat <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100))

## Reshape data wide -> long
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(dat)
plot(value ~ variable, data=long)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @LegalizeIt! I wound up using tidyr to reshape my data into a long df: `library(tidyr)
long <- gather(team1, variable, value, var1:var44) plot(value~variable,data=long)` but wound up with this strange looking plot: http://tinypic.com/r/2rn77no/8 ... Since I have 40+ plots I'm trying to squeeze together, is my original goal moot? If so, I might switch over to panel plots.